# So I want to update the specific value inside the array of object but it is not updating correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

So I tried coping the array and when it matches the memberId I am updating the selected value of the specific object.
It is working for single member.
But let say when there is more than one member then it is not updating correctly.

```
const updateGroupMembers = (memberId: string, optedRider: string, value: string) => {
        
        const updatedMembers = group?.memberDetails?.map((member) =>
            member.memberId === memberId
                ? { ...member, [optedRider]: value }
                : member
        );
       

        if (updatedMembers) {
            setGroup((prevGroup) => ({
                ...prevGroup!,
                memberDetails: updatedMembers,
            }));
        }
    };
```

Comment: What does "not updating correctly" mean? Can you show the expected values and the actual results you're getting? 
I'd also be great if you could add the rest of the code like... where are you calling this method?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this,

```
useEffect(() => {
    setGroup((prevGroup) => ({
      ...prevGroup!,
      memberDetails: updatedMembers,
  }));
  }, [updatedMembers])
```

as soon as the `updatedMembers` updated, useEffect will run.

Comment: The issue is in when I am getting updateMembers.It is not correctly updating the array